# How do I extend an out-of focus background in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, photo-editing

Hey there I am somewhat new to photoshop and here is what I am trying to do. I have a picture like this

[image]

Now I have an area that I have selected and what I want to do is set this to part of the out of focus background. So I want to copy a section of the background that is the same size as my selected area, or the whole blank area and set it to the background.

How can I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you're going to want to use the **clone stamp tool** or the **content aware** fill. Take a look on YouTube for either of these methods. They are fairly simple to use for what you're trying to achieve. Also as a tip: Try to work nondestructively. Working on separate layers for photo corrections will save you frustration in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The best tool to use is the Clone tool, use it with little low opacity. It will work good for the area you want to cover.